# How to override unit Environment configuration via .conf file in systemd?

Tags: systemd

I have this service defined in `/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn-production.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn production daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
PIDFile=/run/gunicorn_production/pid
User=www-data
Group=www-data
RuntimeDirectory=gunicorn_production
WorkingDirectory=/home/production/current
Environment=WORKERS='2'
ExecStart=/home/production/.virtualenvs/production/bin/gunicorn \
-w $WORKERS \
...
# rest of gunicorn configuration parameters
```

The service starts/reloads/stops etc. with the specified 2 workers.

I was going to move all of the hardcoded paths into a configuration file so I can reuse this service definition and I started with defining `WORKERS` in a file in the "drop in" directory: `/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn-production.d/gunicorn-production.conf`:

```
[Service]
Environment=WORKERS='4'
```

If I `systemctl daemon-reload` and then `systemctl restart gunicorn-production` the configuration for 4 workers doesn't take affect. I've tried various configuration/filename permutations but can't seem to override the environment setting via the `.conf` file.

According to the man page systemd.units it looks like a "drop in" directory should do the trick:

> Along with a unit file foo.service, a "drop-in" directory foo.service.d/ may exist. All files with the suffix ".conf" from this directory will be parsed after the file itself is parsed. This is useful to alter or add configuration settings for a unit, without having to modify unit files. Each drop-in file must have appropriate section headers. Note that for instantiated units, this logic will first look for the instance ".d/" subdirectory and read its ".conf" files, followed by the template ".d/" subdirectory and the ".conf" files there. Also note that settings from the "[Install]" section are not honoured in drop-in unit files, and have no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I named the drop-in directory incorrectly. I named it: `/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn-production.d` when it should have been: `/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn-production.service.d`. Once I fixed that the new Environment value was used.

Answer (score 1):

Set the environment to empty first (In theory this should reset the variable) and then set it to 4.

```
[Service]
Environment=
Environment=WORKERS='4'
```

I am not sure if it will work but this is the way to go to reset a systemd unit file token with a drop-in file.

Comment: Thanks @Umut for looking in to this. It turns out that isn't necessary. I named the drop-in directory incorrectly. I named it: ``/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn-production.d`` when it should have been: ``/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn-production.service.d``. Once I fixed that the new Environment value was used and I didn't have to reset the variable.